# Replace multiple strings in pile of text python

Tags: python

If I have the text appleorangepearbanana, I want to replace each instance of apple banana and pear with x and each instance of orange with y. Ideally I would have a dictionary of apple, orange, and banana, and for any instance of this dictionary it would be replaced with x. I'm very new to python so any help would be appreciated :)

Inital text: appleorangepearbanana
Final text: xyxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can easily solve this problem with function str.replace('x', 'y')

```
foo = 'appleorangepearbanana '
foo = foo.replace('apple', 'x').replace('banana', 'x').replace('pear', 'x').replace('orange','y')
print foo
```

To use dictionary and a loop:

```
foo = 'appleorangepearbanana '
dict = {'apple':'x','pear':'x','banana':'x','orange':'y'}
for original,replacewith in dict.items():
    foo = foo.replace(original, replacewith)
print foo
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression might work well here:

```
import re

thedict = dict.fromkeys('apple pear banana'.split(), 'x')
thedict['orange'] = 'y'

theregex = '|'.join(thedict)

def dosub(mo):
    return thedict.get(mo.group(0), '???')

result = re.sub(theregex, dosub, 'appleorangepearbanana')
```

will result in `'xyxx'`, as desired.